# How to automatically fill xml ? linq to xml

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I want to create an XML using Linq (if it works) automatically from data in a database.
For this purpose, my understanding is that placeholders are needed.
How do you insert these placeholders? 
I have shown you my sample XML, I want to keep this format. (Unless it does not work)
I look forward to your answers and thank you in advance.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Xml.Schema;

 namespace LinqToXML1._1
 {
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument exampleDocument= new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("VN_Nr", new XAttribute("VN_Nr(placeholder int)",11),
                new XElement("EI Nubmer" ,3, new XAttribute("NL Number","EI Number(placeholder int) 0000")),
                    new XElement("Serialnumber", 0),
                        new XElement("GM Number(placeholder int)",2),
                         new XElement("FW Number (placeholder string)")
                         )

            ); // Safe file.
        exampleDocument.Save(@"C:");
        Console.WriteLine(exampleDocument.ToString());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your expected XML here? You can't use `(` for attribute, it's special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Well formed XML file has only one root element.  So if you are adding multiple rows from database you need another tag to have VN_numbers where all the data is under this tag.  This is how I would rewrite your code.   You would need to for loop to add each new row from database.  I did not include the loop

Note : you cannot have spaces in tag names and attribute names so I fixed this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string root = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><VN_Numbers></VN_Numbers>"; 
            XDocument exampleDocument = XDocument.Parse(root);

            XElement vnNumbers = exampleDocument.Descendants("VN_Numbers").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement vnNr = new XElement("VN_Nr", new object[] { 
                    new XAttribute("VN_Nr", 11),
                    new XElement("EI_Nubmer", new object[] {new XAttribute("NL_Number", 0000), 3}),
                    new XElement("Serialnumber", 0),
                    new XElement("GM_Number", 2),
                    new XElement("FW_Number")
            });
            vnNumbers.Add(vnNr);

           exampleDocument.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```